# why .htaccess rewrite rule requires exact path?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule -trump(\d{2})\.jpg$     Img.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

I expect all images containing "-trumpXX.jpg" in name, everywhere they are, to redirect to "/_Img-php?id=XX" in the root. Example:

```
/US-trump01.jpg --> /Img.php?id=01
/dir-1/US-trump02.jpg --> /Img.php?id=02
```

But actually it works only with file existing in the root. Why?

Comment: I noticed it starts working only if I add this: "Options -MultiViews". Why?

Comment: Have you read the mod_rewrite documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

"dir-1" is also the name of a file in the root "dir-1.php". So the option "MultiViews", that seems to be active in my server, makes a mess. That's why using "Options -MultiViews" brings RewriteRule to work properly.